Using the library of python "BeautifulSoup", but can not print out the data on the website that I scrapied
Currently, I am using a library of Python called BeautifulSoup to scrapy something from WEBs
But I found that I couldn't print out the data that I scrapied
Here is my code snap shown as below
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
reqget=requests.get('https://fubon-ebrokerdj.fbs.com.tw/z/zg/zg_A_0_5.djhtm') 
html=reqget.text 
sp=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser') 
data = [ i.text.strip() for i in sp.find_all('td',class_='t3t1')] 
print(data)

The output of this code is [] which is empty
Then I went back to check the HTML code of the website that I scrapied.
Indeed, it has the data inside the HTML

So I'm wondering why it can not print out thedata, but the data is indeed existed inside the website that I scrapied?
Expect to get the data from the website that I scrapied

Did you consider checking the returned HTTP status code?

The site you're trying to access requires a User-Agent.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15"
}
url = "https://fubon-ebrokerdj.fbs.com.tw/z/zg/zg_A_0_5.djhtm"

with requests.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BS(response.text, features="lxml")
    data = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("td", class_="t3t1")]
    print(*data, sep="\n")

Output:
6552  易華電
6230  尼得科超眾
1725  元禎
8996  高力
1587  吉茂
6415  矽力*-KY
6449  鈺邦
2739  寒舍
6177  達麗
1459  聯發
6451  訊芯-KY
3563  牧德
2316  楠梓電
3443  創意
2611  志信
6949  沛爾生醫-創
1413  宏洲
1436  華友聯
1457  宜進
3679  新至陞
6442  光聖
2540  愛山林
1516  川飛
5522  遠雄
3030  德律
2423  固緯
1560  中砂
9958  世紀鋼
1446  宏和
8466  美吉吉-KY
9946  三發地產
6176  瑞儀
2345  智邦
2059  川湖
2609  陽明
4967  十銓
6805  富世達
1809  中釉
6283  淳安
2501  國建
6585  鼎基
3017  奇鋐
6235  華孚
2401  凌陽
6933  AMAX-KY
3376  新日興
2359  所羅門
5531  鄉林
3653  健策
2615  萬海


Hi,
Thanks for replying
But how can I get the content of the headers
like this->
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15"
}

@0983 Just hard-code it

>>> import requests
>>> reqget=requests.get('https://fubon-ebrokerdj.fbs.com.tw/z/zg/zg_A_0_5.djhtm')
>>> print(reqget.status_code)
403

The server doesn't return any real data to you.  Given that it works with curl, a bit of User Agent spoofing should do the trick
 % curl -s https://fubon-ebrokerdj.fbs.com.tw/z/zg/zg_A_0_5.djhtm | grep t3r1 --count
174

